# Checkbox on iPhone: Left Border Cut Off

Tags: ios, css, checkbox, woocommerce

Got an issue on pages like [this](https://berthamaesbrownies.com/product/milk-chocolate-toffee-cookies/) where the left border of my checkboxes appear cut off. Looks really unprofessional. Only seems to happen on iOS. I thought I could just add some padding to the div (or margin) but not the case. Is this common?

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px); /*Earlier than iOS 9.0*/
    transform: translate(0px);
}
```

Comment: Answering questions is good but this would be a much better answer if it explained how it works and why it solves the question.

Comment: This definitely fixes it. I remember reading awhile back that if you transform an element, it uses the GPU to do better rendering. Did some googling and couldn't find a source though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your framework ([WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/)?) or plugin/theme for it. It has strange CSS code like this:

```
.single-product div.product .images {
    width: 41.1764705882%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5.8823529412%;
    margin-bottom: 3.631em
}

.single-product div.product .summary {
    width: 52.9411764706%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3.631em
}
```

I don't know why these numbers so fractional, but in this case your checkbox looks OK:

```
.single-product div.product .summary {
    width: 52%;
    ...
}
```

I advice you to figure out why your framework/plugin/theme has so fractional numbers, but if you don't want/can't, you could use workaround with `margin-left: 1px` for your checkbox.

Comment: All that did was make the entire column width go to 52%. And the checkbox left border is still off. So I reverted back.

Comment: And I already tried both margin and padding-left. No change. It's not that.

Comment: @AdamBell I tried it before answer, both cases work well on iPad simulator with iOS 8.3.

Comment: @AdamBell and it'll be better, if you create working code snippet with your issue here or on http://jsfiddle.net.